# Determine ratio of explicit to autocommit transactions on SQL Server table?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2017

**Problem:** To solve data consistency on one of most important tables in our system, all writes will be covered with explicit transactions (appropriate to what given stored procedure / business application is doing). However, since there are many sources of writes, it would be best if we had numerical measure of progress.

Ratio of explicit to autocommited transactions on that particular table would be one such measure. If after all the rework, there are still autocommit transactions in stats, we have proof that we missed some procedure or application (or manual process).

How can SQL server be queried for such information?

Comment: Maybe a XEvent session, with causality tracking, then you can check for `database_transaction_begin` event followed by `sql_statement_completed` or `sql_statement_completed` for which the text contains your table. There will probably be an efficiency hit. Using a trigger and checking `@@TRANCOUNT` will not work, as you can see https://dbfiddle.uk/nNjqwXXd

Comment: In a trigger: `sys.dm_tran_session_transactions.is_user_transaction=1` when DML in a transaction (session_id = @@spid). Sign the trigger for "view server state" permission.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by @lptr you can use `sys.dm_tran_session_transactions` to check if a user transaction was opened.

```sql
CREATE OR ALTER TRIGGER dbo.check_tran
ON dbo.YourTable
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE
AS

SET NOCOUNT ON;

IF (SELECT is_user_transaction FROM sys.dm_tran_session_transactions WHERE session_id = @@SPID) = 1
BEGIN
    INSERT Audit_transactions (host_name, user_name, initial_batch)
    SELECT HOST_NAME(), SUSER_SNAME(), CONCAT(b.parameters, '  ', b.event_info)
    FROM sys.dm_exec_requests r
    OUTER APPLY sys.dm_exec_input_buffer (@@SPID, r.request_id) b
    WHERE r.session_id = @@SPID
END;
```

`sys.dm_tran_session_transactions` requires `VIEW SERVER STATE` permissions, so if the user does not have that then you may need to sign the trigger with a certificate of a user that has that permission.